# Ошибка какая-то

Tags: php

```
 // получение данных из файла
    $str = file_get_contents("C:\OSPanel\domains\MyMainProject\ ".$_SESSION['user']['login'].'.txt');
    $data = unpacking($str);
```

> Warning: file_get_contents(C:\OSPanel\domains\MyMainProject\ \k1ngly.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OSPanel\domains\MyMainProject\kabinet.php on line 6
>   Ошибка!

Comment: использую вместо тебя переводчик, не надо благодарности . Предупреждение: file_get_contents (C: \ OSPanel \ domains \ MyMainProject \ \ k1ngly.txt): не удалось открыть поток: нет такого файла или каталога в C: \ OSPanel \ domains \ MyMainProject \ kabinet.php в строке 6

Comment: print_r($str); сделай и посмотри строку на ошибку

Answer (score 7):

0. Ошибка не "какая-то", а её надо читать.

   У тебя пробел перед кавычкой лишний.

   А на сервере точно винда?

   Полазий и посмотри файловую структуру - что там есть и чего там нет.

   Винда в пути два слеша подряд поймёт, а линукс - не факт.

   А ещё этот код - дыра в безопасности если в логине может быть `/../` или подобное.

Comment: А также лучше использовать или $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] или __DIR__ и относительно него писать путь

Comment: @iproger, я в php не разбираюсь - написал что вижу. Можешь отдельным ответом дать.

Comment: Ну вот будет уроком автору в дыре безопасности. Там как минимум можно под любым пользователем войти, зная только логин. Не знаю что движет такими людьми которые придумывают подобное. Обычно при изучении они по урокам/гайдам что-то пишут, основываясь на полученных знаниях, тогда кто тот человек, кто научил подобному кодингу.